# How to add List<T> data type in Properties of Application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, .net-4.7.2

I want to add `List<T>` Data type to my `Application Setting` but I couldn't do it.

When I go to the `Project Setting > Properties` and declare a new field and try to Browse the type, I find `System.Collections.Generic` but there is no `List<T>` inside of it.

Could someone please help?

Comment: declare `using System.Collections.Generic;` on top of the class

Comment: In short, the post is not acceptable. What exactly stops you from adding the type? Compile error? Runtime error? What the errer text? You can't add `List<T>` but can you add `List<string>`? Can you add more details into the question? You may edit it.

Comment: @aepot when i go to the Project Setting>Properties and declare new field and try to Browse the type i find the System.Collections.Generic but there is no List<T> inside it.

Comment: @viveknuna it's already there.

Comment: @leftOne  `List<T>` is defined in `System.Collections.Generic` only

Comment: Why do you need adding `List` to Properties? Properties class is not intended to be a data storage. As well it's not optimized for that. You may store the data to a file or database.

Comment: I would recommend using an array `T[]` instead of `List<T>` as the type, as settings, reads or writes all at once, and it will never use the functionality of lists such as `.Add()`.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by following these steps.

1. add a new property lets call it `setting` and give it a `string` data type
   [image]
2. save your settings file then go in the solution explorer to `settings.cs > settings > setting : string`
   [image]
3. change the setting data type to `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`. lets assume that `T` is `int` for now, then change the default value as in the picture
   [image]
4. save the `Settings.cs` so that your changes are applied.